# Validation on hierarchical alike structure

Tags: c#, linq, hierarchy

Suppose there is a DataTable as below :

[image]

Each row is a combination of (N1,N2,N3,N4), with this constraints:

- Only N1, N2, N3 and N4 are nullable
- In each row column N(n) could be NULL only if N(n-1) is NULL.(something like hierarchical structure).
- each combination of (N1, N2, N3, N4) is unique within whole set.

I am looking for a solution by which for whole set,"No combination must has a value in it's Amount column which is smaller than sum of its sub-combinations";.

For example Amount of row:1 must be greater than sum of rows:2,10,11 and consequently Amount of row:2 must be greater than sum of rows:3,4,5,6,7,8,9 (which of-course in given case is not valid).

My development environment is C#.net and using Linq is preferred.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ¿Que? - I think you need to explain your example better. Otherwise I hope some people smarter than me can help you.

Comment: @Enigmativity; Think of a budgeting tree which is consist of 4 level of data.  
but in my case data structure is not hierarchical (self reference) and is done by 4 fixed column.  I hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your data or your examples. I think you might need to do a full manual calculation on your data and show us the working.

Answer (score 0):

You could pull together a method that decides a parent-child relationship for two `Tuple<N1,N2,N3,N4>`-like objects. Idea:bit array representation and shifts. With this naive model:

```
public class Budget
{
public int Id { get; set; }
//
public int N1 { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> N2 { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> N3 { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> N4 { get; set; }
//
public float Amount { get; set; }
/// <summary>
/// Method analyzes if current object is a parent of <paramref name="other"/>
/// if you override GetHashCode or provide a nifty bit array representation 
/// you can infer parent-child relationships with really fast bit shifting 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="other">budget to compare with</param>    
public bool IsParentOf (Budget other)
{
  // ommitted for too-time-consuming and 'your work obviously' 
  // or 'not-the-purpose-of-this-site'reasons
  return true;
}
}
```

you might try getting subcombinations(your taxonomy here) for every budget entry:

```
  Budget b1 = new Budget() { N1 = 1, N2 = null, N3 = null, N4 = null, Amount = 1200f };
  Budget b11 = new Budget() { N1 = 1, N2 = 1, N3 = null, N4 = null, Amount = 800f };
  Budget b111 = new Budget() { N1 = 1, N2 = 1, N3 = 1, N4 = null, Amount = 800f };
  Debug.Assert (b1.IsParentOf(b11));
  Debug.Assert(b1.IsParentOf(b111));
  Debug.Assert(b11.IsParentOf(b111));
  var budgetEntries = new List<Budget>() { b11, b111 };
  var subCombinations = budgetEntries.Where(be => b1.IsParentOf(be));
  Debug.Assert(b1.Amount > subCombinations.Sum(sc => sc.Amount));
```

Of course for a whole dataset of budget entries you'd have to match every entry against all the others like a cartesian product. I don't claim this is fast, but it definitely should do the job.